# How can we extract Azure keyvault value using C# console application using a service account or user account

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Looking for something similar in C#

```
$AzAccount = Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $SPOAdminCredentials
$clientId = (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -vaultName $KeyVaultName -name $KVSecName_ProvFnClientId).SecretValueText
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to my code, here is detailed [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net#sample-code):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

 

namespace key_vault_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string secretName = "testxxx";
            var kvUri = "https://tinytestxxxx.vault.azure.net/";
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());

 

            var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
            Console.WriteLine($"Your secret is '{secret.Value.Value}'.");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Next, you need to [add the account to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281683/how-to-set-a-secret-in-azure-key-vault-from-a-local-asp-net-application):

[image]